# Get the date and time without a time zone using a date time picker

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I have a form with date time pickers like this one:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-placeholder>Time Window Start</mat-placeholder>
    <mat-datetimepicker-toggle [for]="datetimePickerStart" matSuffix></mat-datetimepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datetimepicker
      #datetimePickerStart
      type="datetime"
      openOnFocus="true"
      timeInterval="5">
    </mat-datetimepicker>
    <input
      matInput
      formControlName="datestart"
      [matDatetimepicker]="datetimePickerStart"
      required
      autocomplete="false">
  </mat-form-field>
```

What I want is to get the UTC time, so I also added this in my `app.module.ts`:

```
{
    provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATETIME_FORMATS,
    useValue: {useUtc: true}
},
{
    provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS,
    useValue: {useUtc: true}
}
```

I then get the value like this:

```
var datestart: Moment = this.form.get('datestart').value;
```

But when I enter a date, let's say the 11th of November at 12:00PM, the date I get is 11th of November at 10:00PM (the value in the input is `11/11/2020 10:00 PM` and the value returned by `this.form.get('datestart').value;` is `2020-11-11T10:00:00.000Z`). What I need is for the date picker to return me `2020-11-11T12:00:00.000Z`. How do I get that ?

Comment: you might to do use moment-zone(https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use `{useUtc: true}` it takes you current time and converts it to UTC which makes 12PM become 10PM.
Try not using `{useUtc: true}`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was, as suggested by Tom, to use Moment-Timezone:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

var datestart = moment.tz(this.form.get('datestart').value, moment.tz.guess());
console.log(datestart.format("YYYY-MM-DDTH:mm:ss.SSS") + 'Z');
```

Here, `moment.tz.guess()` returns the timezone (`"Europe/Berlin"`), and `moment.tz()` creates a date in the detected timezone.